# Can't resolve firebase config file React

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm new to React and I'm trying to create a Firebase web app using it. When I created my initial build, I put my firebase configuration in a separate js file from my app. When I try and run `npm start` to test it, I get the following error:

```
./src/Login.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebaseConfig' in 'C:\Users\...\...\...\...\src'
```

The file in question is below:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth"
import React from "react";
const config = {
    //relevant configuration details
};
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);

export default firebaseApp;
```

I'm using it in other js files via

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import firebaseApp from "firebaseConfig";
```

I've tried deleting the file and rewriting it. I've checked my directories to make sure I have the correct dependencies and the firebaseConfig file is in the same folder as the Login file. I'm stuck. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Have your configured your webpack for absolute path imports?

Comment: You should use:  import firebaseApp from "./firebaseConfig"

Comment: @Michael wow that actually worked. Why is the "./" needed?

Comment: @NakulUpadhya Plz, upvote for my answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use: import firebaseApp from "./firebaseConfig"